# Why my "foreach" C# code doesn't loop through all items in listBox?

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, listbox

**What is expected**: tool to do task on each item, one by one in the listbox.

**What is happening:** tool does the task only on the user selected item in the listbox. And nothing else.

Code:

```
 int index;
        string item;
        foreach (int i in listBox1.SelectedIndices)
        {
            index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
            item = listBox1.Items[index].ToString();
            texteditor.Documents.Open(@item);
        }
```

Comment: You're ignoring `i`, have you tried using `.SelectedItems` also? is this winforms/wpf?

Comment: You iterate over `SelectedIndices` but don't use them? Maybe removing the line `index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;` and changing `.Items[index]` to `.Items[i]`will help. But you could use `SelectedItems` and get the items directly.

Comment: Your code does exactly what you wrote. Why iterate only the selected items if you want all???

Comment: @AndreasWard - any of the answers helped you to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

this should iterate through all items

```
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
    texteditor.Documents.Open(item.ToString());
}
```

Comment: An explanation on why 'this should work' may help them better understand where they went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over selected items, whereas you want to interate over all the items in your list box.

Also, the correct way to iterate over a ListBox returns a ListItem and not an int.

Try this:

```
 string item;
 foreach (ListItem li in listBox1.Items)
 {
     item = li.ToString();
     texteditor.Documents.Open(@item);
 }
```

I also removed the index variable from your code. If you needed the index for something else you would need a for loop like this:

```
 string item;
 for (int index = 0; index < listBox1.Items.Count; index++) {
     item = listBox1.Items[index].ToString();
     texteditor.Documents.Open(@item);
     // do something with index
 }
```

Comment: `foreach (int i in listBox1.Items)` should return the item and not the index